# User not allowed to use crontab

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I want to edit cron tab daily to delete / add some jobs .. so I added cron job ( helper job ) to run php script to handle these edits.

When I run this script by browser works fine .. but when it runs using the helper job not running and I receive notification mail from cpanel with this error :

**Please note I am on shared hosting plan with C-Panel so I have no root access .. but the code working fine when run from browser.**

**Error:**

```
You (dcfn35c8st1b) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)
See crontab(1) for more information
You (dcfn35c8st1b) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)
See crontab(1) for more information
You (dcfn35c8st1b) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)
See crontab(1) for more information
You (dcfn35c8st1b) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)
See crontab(1) for more information
You (dcfn35c8st1b) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)
See crontab(1) for more information
```

**PHP Script:**

```
exec('crontab -l', $crontab);
$record_found = false;
foreach($crontab as $key => $value){
    if(strpos($value, 'record_extra.php') !== false){
        //echo $key . ' ' . $value . '<br>';
        unset($crontab[$key]);
        $record_found = true;
    }
        if(strpos($value, 'record.php') !== false){
        //echo $key . ' ' . $value . '<br>';
        unset($crontab[$key]);
    }
}
if($record_found){
    file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', arrayToString($crontab) . $firstJob.PHP_EOL);
    if(exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt')){
        //echo 'success <br>'; 
    } else {
        //echo 'error <br>'; 
    }
    $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
    file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output . $secondJob.PHP_EOL);
    if(exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt')){
        //echo 'success <br>'; 
    } else {
        //echo 'error <br>'; 
    }
} else {
    $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
    file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output . $firstJob.PHP_EOL);
    if(exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt')){
        //echo 'success <br>'; 
    } else {
        //echo 'error <br>'; 
    }
    $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
    file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output . $secondJob.PHP_EOL);
    if(exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt')){
        //echo 'success <br>'; 
    } else {
        //echo 'error <br>'; 
    }
}
```

*Need your help.
Thanks in advance.*

Comment: So most likely permissions issue. And why do you run crontab from script instead of just editing `/etc/cron.daily` file?

Comment: This seems to be a security program like SELinux or AppArmor. You need to find which one your system is using and grant user dcfn35c8st1b the appropriate privileges.

Comment: Please note I am on shared hosting plan with C-Panel so i have no root access .. but the code working fine when run from browser

Comment: Even if your web server PHP processes run under the same user than command-line PHP (I don't know if that's the case), permissions can be set differently.

Comment: Well a couple of things here:  newer Linux distros have deprecated cron in favor of systemd.  So this is chasing something that is non-standard at best (linux has anacron!) and this is also not how cron was really designed to work.  To programmatically inject jobs that change daily, I would suggest looking into the use of "at" instead, which is really made for this use case imnsho

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the user isn't allowed to run crontab. Look into the files "/etc/cron.allow" and "/etc/cron.deny". If cron.allow exists, then only users in that list can use crontab. Users in cron.deny, can't use. If neither exist then only root user can use crontab.

Comment: not really true, if none of these exist - all users can use it

Comment: @FlashThunder To allow all users you should have an empty cron.deny file. However it should exist I believe.

Comment: Please note I am on shared hosting plan with C-Panel so i have no root access .. but the code working fine when run from browser

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at numerous "can't run crontab" posts and none of them addressed my problem. I want to report my unique solution.

My service provider copied my system to another place, and apparently they literally used the "cp" command to do it, which meant that no setuid bits were preserved. /usr/bin/crontab was one of several files for which I had to restore the setuid bit.

You can't run crontab if it doesn't have the setuid bit set.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32892843)

Answer (score 0):

The following can fix `You (dcfn35c8st1b) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)`  in `redhat 9`

`echo dcfn35c8st1b > /etc/cron.allow`

> CRONTAB(1)

> Scheduling  cron  jobs  with crontab can be allowed or disallowed for different users.  For this purpose, use the cron.allow and cron.deny files.  If the cron.allow file exists, a user must be listed in it to be allowed to use crontab.  If the
> cron.allow file does not exist but the cron.deny file does exist, then a user must not be listed in the cron.deny file in order to use crontab.  If neither of these files exist, then only the super user is allowed to use crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Allow crontab for all uses

Issue:

```
$ crontab -e
You (shanewa) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)
See crontab(1) for more information
```

Solution:

Create an empty `/etc/cron.deny`,

```
$ sudo touch /etc/cron.deny
```